# Is there any way to run the React Native app on Android while making android:exported as "false" in AndroidManifest.xml file without an error?

Tags: android, react-native, security, android-manifest, penetration-testing

This is a test project AndroidManifest.xml file. Due to some security compliances, I need to make the property android:exported="true"or the MainActivity. But If I try to do the same it doesn't let me run the react native app on android. Is there any way to make the project run while making exported value as false ?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried making the exported false in the AndroidManifest.xml file directly but it doesn't seem to be working.